# Why doesn't this async function throw undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a pretty simple async function that calls the fetch api, and brings me back some data. I am using the `await` keyword 2 times in this function, and then getting that data and pushing it into my component state.

Here is my pseudo-code in regards to how this function is executing (please tell me if I'm right or wrong here):

1. Call the fetch api with `await`: this allows the rest of your code to continue to the next line.
2. Once you get the fetch the response stream, put it into `data` variable. Again, the code can continue while we are waiting for this to happen.
3. Log the data to the console.

Step 3 is where I have some questions...let's say I'm on a really terrible network, and my fetch request doesn't give me my data for 5 full seconds. At that point, shouldn't my `console.log(data)` line throw undefined, and execute the `catch` block, due to the async function allowing `console.log(data` to run BEFORE I get my fetch data back?

I tested this by going into the Chrome Web dev console, and selected the "slow 3g" connection. Even with that network, I was able to log my data to the console without throwing `undefined`.

What I want to do is to **make sure there is data to push into state** right after I get my data object back.

```
 getMovieDetails = async id => {
    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
    const movieId = id;
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`;
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({
        title: data.title,
        poster: data.poster_path
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Couldn't fetch the endpoint!`);
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: or else try Promise instead await/aync methods. Have you tried that?

Comment: It's still unclear why you expect it to throw. *due to the async function allowing console.log(data to run BEFORE I get my fetch data back?* - why should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong in the first point of your Pseudo-code

> Call the fetch api with await: this allows the rest of your code to
>   continue to the next line.

Actually, no. `await` will block the execution of the next lines in the `async` function.

So,

```
yourAsyncFunction = async () => {
  await doSomething();
  console.log('done something') // Will not run until doSomething() gets completed
}
```

Which is why you are always getting the fetched data in your `console.log(data)` statement.

Comment: Ah, it blocks the whole function; my understanding of it was incorrect. Thank you for clearing that up!